# How can I load dynamic images in my TableView given my code format?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am learning swift and I finally found how to load images asynchronously . What I am trying to do now is pass that code to my TableView however I am a bit stumped on how to do that given how my code files are structured . First of here is the code that shows a single image.

**login.swift:**

```
let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "my-url")!
let request:NSURLRequest =  NSURLRequest(url: imgURL as URL)
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
        self.Profile_Image.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    })
});

task.resume()
```

That code above correctly renders an image now I want to pass that code and insert it into a TableView: I have 2 files 1 for the TableViewCell and the other a controller with a TableView .

**TableViewCell.swift:**

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var fullname: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var profile_image: UIImageView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

}
```

**Controller.swift:**

```
class Controller: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource {
    var FullName = [String]()
    var profile_image_string = [String]()
    @IBOutlet weak var TableSource: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       TableSource.dataSource = self
       getJsonData()
    }

    func getJsonData() {

  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {

            } else {
                do {
                    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]

                    if let Streams = parsedData["JsonData"] as? [AnyObject]  {

                        for Stream in Streams {
                            if let fullname = Stream["fullname"] as? String {
                                self.FullName.append(fullname)
                            }

                            if let profile_picture = Stream["profile_image"] as? String {
                                self.profile_image_string.append(profile_picture)
                            }

                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           self.TableSource.reloadData()

                        }
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

        }).resume()
}



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TVC", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.fullname.setTitle(FullName[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.profile_image.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
    }

}
```

Ok so at the top of my controller class I have the variable **var profile_image_string** which basically saves all the different URL's that are coming from the Json then I append it by using this code

```
  if let profile_picture = Stream["profile_image"] as? String {
                                self.profile_image_string.append(profile_picture)
                            }
```

now I only have access to the ImageView property inside the TableView code, how can I display my image ? if you can see the code inside the TableView(UITableViewCell) I access the imageView by doing this

```
cell.profile_image. ///
```

any suggestions would be great ...

Comment: Use this library: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher, Very simple to use, in your cellForRowAtIndex use: let url = URL(string: "url_of_your_image")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your `cellForRowAt` method like below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TVC", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.fullname.setTitle(FullName[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.profile_image.tag = indexPath.row

        /* Set your cell image here*/
           let strCellImageURL = yourArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)

           let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: strCellImageURL)!
           let request:NSURLRequest =  NSURLRequest(url: imgURL as URL)
           let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
           let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

           let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,    completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
          DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
          cell.Profile_Image.image = UIImage(data: data!)
      })
     });

        return cell
    }
```

I think if something good is already available in Native so why should we go with Third Party Classes.

If you need any clarification then you can comment me below.

Comment: your most welocome :)